# Custom Button to Validate picklist fields in case Object

Tags: custom-button

I have five picklist fields in case object and one custom button named "Open case".When I click on this button it has to check whether five fields contains values or not.If values are there it has to Open otherwise it shows error message stating that these fields should not be blank.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? You are unlikely to get help unless you show that you have attempted it first yourself.

Comment: I am new to javascript

Comment: @user10921 - The do some reading, find similar topics, try something, and the update your question. This is not a forum to write cord for you. We can provide you with plenty of links to consulting parters who would be happy to write it for you for a fee. --See below for a start though

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write some JAVASCRIPT for the button.

1. Start by Including the required JS for the button

   {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")} //adds the proper code for inclusion of AJAX toolkit
2. You will need to perform a query to check the value of the pick lists

   var sQuery = "Select fields From object where ID = '{!obj.id}'"; 
   var result = sforce.connection.query(sQuery);
3. Then you will have to parse through the results and if they meet the requirements then open the case
4. If it fails then present a message

That should give you a start.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using flow?  I'm not going to build the Flow for you... but go google Visual Flow and see how easy you could build this with a Record Lookup and a Decision element to determine if a field is NULL.  If one is blank you could even show that field so they can fill it out then and there!  Assuming you want them to fill this information out, this would be a great way to automate the process!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a javascript button like that

```
var allCorect =  {! NOTISBLANK(Case.Picklist1__c) && NOTISBLANK(Case.Picklist2__c) && NOTISBLANK(Case.Picklist3__c) && NOTISBLANK(Case.Picklist4__c) && NOTISBLANK(Case.Picklist5__c)};

if(allCorrect)
    top.location = '/'+VISUAL_FlOW_URL;
else
    alert('Picklist cant be empty ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use Validation rules on the Case?  If the fields are required to Save, then a validation checking for non-default values should address this declaratively rather than with a button/code?